# PHPStorm go to a specific tab

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, phpstorm

I would like in PHPStorm to go to the no. 2 tab/file using a keyboard shortcut, just like you would do for chrome or sublime, when you want to go to the second tab you hit alt+2 or ctrl+2.

Any ideas if this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that is not possible (unless, there is some new (unknown to me yet) plugin that can do that).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress. Based on developers feedback -- this is not in their priority list...